# Twitter Boostrap Dropdown Load Ajax Content

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

I can't figure out how to load content into a Bootstrap dropdown menu when it is opened.
I cant even get it to log something when the trigger is clicked.

```
<span class="dropdown">
  <a class="btn btn-mini btn-info dropdown-toggle insert-gallery" id="dLabel" role="button" data-media-id="50" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Add To Gallery
    <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel"></ul>
</span>

$('.insert-gallery').on('click', function(){
  var media_id = $(this).data('media-id');
  console.log(media_id);
  console.log('click');
});
```

Console doesn't log anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hacked version of the drop down plugin that posts to the href and posts inline data attributes in the request.

http://pastebin.com/fRWJaL6L

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the workaround as the plugin currently returns false on a click event.

Remove  the data-toggle and the following:

```
$(document).on("click", ".dropdown-toggle", function(event) {
  // Ajax actions here 
  $(this).attr("data-toggle", "dropdown").click();
});
```

Comment: Actually, this only works for the first click on each item. The ajax requested is only run only on the first click.